# ArrayList Java BlueJ

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I have 4 classes (Car (superclass), CarToRent, CarToSell, and CarCompany). CarCompany creates a GUI in the constructor. I need to store an Array List in class CarCompany of Car. How do I do this? Please help.

Also, the main method in CarCompany is currently:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  CarCompany = new CarCompany();
}
```

IS this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No this is incorrect, you have only specified a type but you haven't given it a name:

try:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  CarCompany myCarCompany= new CarCompany();
}
```

now `myCarCompany` is an Object of type `CarCompany`.

**Compiling**

When you compile inside of your IDE or from the command line, the compiler will pick up those errors and tell you what is wrong. It is important to be able to test and debug code on your own since sometimes no one will be there to help.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be  `CarCompany carCompany = new CarCompany();`

Second, if the four classes extend the same class, let's say `Car`, you can create it like that:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
//and then
cars.add(new Car());
cars.add(new CarToRent());
// etc...
```

If they don't have the same super class, then you'll need to either put them in `List<Object>` or in four different lists.